# OrderBy not being respected for item field when using content search

Tags: content-search, lucene

Using `Lucene`, and `content search` I cannot sort items by their name nor custom title field.

The items are imported from a read-only data provider and are successfully indexed (I've inspected it manually)

The results I get back are semi-in-order but not but incoherent. Without the orderby clause, the items are more in-order than without it which is unusual.

Here's the simplified code:

```
ProviderSearchContext
  .GetQueryable<MyCustomSearchResultItem>()
  .Filter(m => m.TemplateId == "{SomeGuid}") 
  .OrderBy(m => m.Title) 
  .Skip(20 * (Page - 1))
  .Take(20)   
  .GetResults() 

public class MyCustomSearchResultItem: SearchResultItem {
        [IndexField("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lucene uses tokenization for the fields. Since most string fields have spaces so it will not work with OrderBy without proper configuration.

In the Lucene configuration file's `fieldNames` block section, you will need to make sure the field you are using for "ordering by" is specified. In addition, an analyzer is needed to ensure it is added to the index documents correctly. You can specify a custom analyzer as a child of the field element in the `fieldMap` section. it will look like this -

```
<fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
   <field fieldName="sortingField" storageType="YES" indexType="UN_TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
       <analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
   </field>
   ...
</fields>
```

the indexType value should be `“UN_TOKENIZED”`, to make sure OrderBy clause to use the entire string for ordering and not the tokens.

Comment: I should also mention, we search on this field too. Wouldn't that also affect search? Does the same thing apply to the Item Name? Because in our context `ItemName == Title` where possible. I ordering was causing a problem there too.

Comment: @AdamHess you have the same field with different name tokenized and untokenized, so the tokenized used for search and the untokenized used for ordering.

Comment: @TamásTárnok is correct, you can define the same field with a different name.

Comment: Google solr copyfield

Comment: @TamásTárnok it looks like the untokenized is specified in one of the default sitecore configs. If i understand things correctly the fieldName has to match the item's field name...however this will cause a lot of conflict with other items (they all use the same generic name of `title`) is there a way to indicate it should be indexed based on the fieldid instead? My current solution is to create a computed field, but i feel like there should be something out of the box to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Sitecore automatically tokenizes the field I'm interested in.

Found inside Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config:

`<field fieldName="title" storageType="NO" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />`

This in tern causes the field to be broken up into multidimensional commponents rather than a single field to be sorted on.

More about this can be found here: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecore_7_development_team/posts/sorting-and-ordering-results-in-sitecore-7